# How are pointers stored in memory?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a little confused about this.
On my system, if I do this:

```
printf("%d", sizeof(int*));
```

this will just yield 4. Now, the same happens for `sizeof(int)`. Conclusion: if both integers and pointers are 4 bytes, a pointer can be safely "converted" to an int
 (i.e. the memory it points to could be stored in an int). However, if I do this:

```
int* x;
printf("%p", x);
```

The returned hex address is far beyond the int scope, and thus any attempt to store the value in an int fails obviously.

How is this possible? If the pointer takes 4 bytes of memory, how can it store more than 2<sup>32</sup>?

EDIT:
As suggested by a few users, I'm posting the code and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(int*));

    int *x;
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    printf ("%p\n", x);
}
```

The output:

```
4
4
4
0xb7778000
```

Comment: "The returned hex address is far beyond the int scope" - are you sure? How many non-zero bytes does it print? Is that just an unsigned <-> signed range issue?

Comment: You should not print the result of the application of `sizeof` with `%d`. Do `printf("%d", (int)sizeof(int*));` or `printf("%zu", sizeof(int*));`

Comment: No, a pointer can be *unsafely* converted to an integer.  And the memory a pointer points to could be megabytes -- not gonna fit in an integer.

Comment: I can't recreate these results.  What compiler?  I take it both programs are compiled under the same OS-bitness? (looks like 1 is under 32bit and 2 is under 64bit)

Comment: Of course they are. It's gcc under a 32-bit ubuntu.

Comment: sizeof operator can tell you how much memory a piece of data will occupy.Pointers have different size on different machines. Suppose if int took 2 bits on 32 bit machine then it will took 4 bit on 64 bit machine and <b>Pointers are not hex value of any data stored in it.</b> it is just like <b>Web LINK</b> that actually points to some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C11, 6.3.2.3, paragraphs 5 and 6:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

So the conversions are allowed, but the result is implementation defined (or undefined if the result cannot be stored in an integer type). (The "previously specified" is referring to NULL.)

In regards to your print statement for a pointer printing something larger than what 4 bytes of data can represent, this is not true, as `0xb7778000` is within range of a 32 bit integral type.

Comment: Apparentely I'm missing something. 0xb7778000 is 3078062080 in decimal. That's more than 2^31.

Comment: @szczurcio: You’re missing something. 2^32 is 4294967296. Counting the characters in the hex representation is enough, anyways: b7778000 is 8 characters.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about signed int and 2^31. Ok, so I guess it is clear now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @szczurcio: The largest unsigned 32 bit number is `0xffffffff`.

Comment: I haven't slept for 24 hours and I think this could be considered the explanation of my (temporary I hope) stupidity. That should have been obvious... Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The returned hex address is far beyond the int scope, and thus any attempt to store the value in an int fails obviously.

```
4
4
4
0xb7778000
```

And `0xb7778000` is a `32`-bit value, so an object of `4` bytes can hold it.

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot be "safely" converted.  Certainly they use the same amount of storage space, but there is no guarantee that they interpret a number of set bits in the same manner.

As for the second question (and one question per question please), there is no guaranteed size for int, or for a pointer.  An int is roughly the optimum size of data transfer on the bus (also known as a word).  It can differ on different platforms, but must be relatively (equal or) larger than a short or char.  This is why there are standard definitions for MAX_INT, but not a standard "value" for the definition.

A pointer is roughly the number of bits wide as necessary to access a memory location.  The old original PC's had a 8 bit bus, but a 12 bit pointer (due to some fancy bit-shifting) to extend it's memory range past its bus size.

Comment: Does typecasting between primitives ever change the data, or just its interpretation?

Comment: @Aggieboy depends on the typecast.  If there is enough storage, often it only changes the interpretation; however, if there isn't enough storage, it certainly has to potential to change the data.